# Problem with Ralink Wifi card

Tags: wireless, hp, ralink

My laptop is hp probook 4520s and I have a wireless interface ralink.

After running `lshw -C network`, the results are:

```
   *-network DISABLED      
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3090 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: RaLink
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:44:00.0
   logical name: ra0
   version: 00
   serial: e0:2a:82:55:22:c0
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN driverversion=2.4.0.4 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
   resources: irq:19 memory:d0300000-d030ffff
```

But when I type `airmon-ng` it shows like this :

```
ra0             Ralink 2560 PCI rt2500
```

Please can anyone help me. I need to stop using the `rt2500` driver and install the `rt3090` driver.

My linux kernel version is 3.2.6.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of Ubuntu you're using, but Markus Tisoft builds helped me out when I was having problems with rt3090

https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/rt3090